# How to run use effect in App.js while using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, use-effect

I want to  run `getUser` function every time the user goes to some other link.
The following is my `getUser` function

```
const getUser = async () => {

    if (localStorage.getItem('access') === null || localStorage.getItem('refresh') === null || localStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
      setUser({ email: null });
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
      return;
    }

    const responseForAccessToken = await verifyTokenAPI(localStorage.getItem('access'));
    console.log(responseForAccessToken);

    if (responseForAccessToken.status >= 400) {
      const newAccessTokenResponse = await getAccessTokenAPI(localStorage.getItem('refresh'));
      console.log(newAccessTokenResponse);

      if (newAccessTokenResponse.status >= 400) {
        localStorage.removeItem('access');
        localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        setUser({ email: null });
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
        return;
      }

      localStorage.removeItem('access');
      localStorage.setItem('access', newAccessTokenResponse.access);
    }
```

I want to verify token every time the user changes routes. Therefore, I used `getUser` function in `useEffect` in my `App.js`

```
const history = useHistory();
const { getUser } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((location) => {
      console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`);
    });
    getUser();
  }, [history]);
```

Every time I change routes the `useEffect` runs and console logs the message but does not run `getUser` function.

I am using `Link` from `react-router-dom`

```
<h1>Welcome {user.email}</h1>

      <Link to="/protected-route-2">Protected Route 2</Link>
      <button
        onClick={() => logout({ callBack: () => history.push("/login") })}
      >
        Logout
      </button>
```

Additionally, I also have a `PrivateRoute` component

```
const Privateroute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { isLoggedIn, getUser } = useAuth()
  console.log(isLoggedIn);
  const location = useLocation()
  if (isLoggedIn) return <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} />;
  return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: location.pathname } }} />
}
```

I am not sure if I am doing things right. Can someone suggest another approach to this problem? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `useLocation` hook (as shown in [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)) instead of the `useHistory`, which would give you the current location and use that as the dependency for the `useEffect`:

```
const location = useLocation();
const { getUser } = useAuth();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`);
  getUser();
}, [location]);
```

In your code, the `history` object does not change and the effect is only fired once, the reason you keep getting the console logs when the location changes is that you added a listener to the history.